# Grails GORM: list all with nested property

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

My (simplified) domain model looks like this:

```
class Student { 
    static hasMany = [professions:StudentProfession];
}

class StudentProfession { 
    static belongsTo = [student:Student];
    Profession profession;
}

class Profession { 
    String name;
}
```

What is the most efficient way to:

> List all students that are taught "Programmer" and "Manager" professions

Am I forced to filter them out after querying the database?

```
students = students.findAll { student -> 
    student.professions.find { professionNames.contains(it.profession.name) } != null
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using a GORM query:

```
def studends = Student.where {
  professions {
      profession.name == "Programmer" || profession.name == "Manager"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ways to skin this cat - here's one:

```
StudentProfession.findAllByProfessionInList(Profession.findAllByNameInList(["Programmer","Manager"])*.student.unique()
```